# SVG <image> not showing up in Edge

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, microsoft-edge

I have an inline svg in my HTML and the image portion isn't showing correctly.

I looked around some other posts on here and they mention to try playing with the viewbox and also try setting the width in css for the image, but i'm not having any luck.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that it works fine in chrome, but Edge / IE is where i'm having the issue of the image not showing.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 972 254" class="vhr-car">
         <image xlink:href="https://images.dealer.com/ddc/vehicles/2019/Honda/HR-V/SUV/color/Milano%20Red-R_81-114,4,19-640-en_US.jpg" x="50%" transform="translate(-190, 0)" width="400" class="svg__hrv"></image>
    </svg>
```

Comment: please try giving your image a height too

Comment: I agree with the suggestion given by @enxaneta. If we add height attribute than image is displaying fine in IE and Edge browser. See here: https://i.postimg.cc/zDFC1jpr/242.png I suggest  enxaneta to post his suggestion as an answer so that Jacob J can mark it as an answer may help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: It does reveal itself if i ad the height inline. Any ideas on how to make that height responsive then?